# sqlMessage: 'Field \'winner_statustext\' doesn\'t have a default value',

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, ubuntu

i try to start a script using pm2
and i get this error
just so you know winner_statustext cant have an default value
i really dont know why it dosent work maybe you guys can help me fix it
any help is welcome

```
0|unencryp |   code: 'ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD',
0|unencryp |   errno: 1364,
0|unencryp |   sqlMessage: 'Field \'winner_statustext\' doesn\'t have a default value',
0|unencryp |   sqlState: 'HY000',
0|unencryp |   index: 0,
0|unencryp |   sql:
0|unencryp |    'INSERT INTO raffles SET tipul = 0, item_id = \'0\' , item_name = \'1500 Coins\', item_image = \'http://192.168.1.12/vendor/img/icon-coins.png\', item_price = 1500, slots = 2\n    , price_per_ticket = 810, hash = \'811dc42ad7cda83acae9361372d553982d561f67758943f159258ab266cdd1d1\', secrets = \'aSj92RWD8CPciD9C-SJauifbo9pNsIQMc\', secret_winner = \'SJauifbo9pNsIQMc\'\n    , secret_number = 1, time = 1612732948' }
```

Comment: I assume that the winner_statustext field is set to not null and value must be provided when inserting?

Comment: i dont know thats why i need help